# Volley POST throws error on successful request

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm using Volley `StringRequest` to post a query to my server and I seeing  that in about 20% of cases, the request is successful but `onErrorResponse` is called instead of `onResponse`.

Here is my request code:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
  new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
      Log.d("App", "[MainActivity] post successful");

      // run very important routine only when post is successful
    }
  }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
      Log.e("App", "[MainActivity] failed to post");

      if (error == null) {
        Log.e("App", "no error");
      } 
      else if (error.networkResponse != null) {
        Log.e("App", String.valueOf(error.networkResponse.statusCode));
        if(error.networkResponse.data != null) {
          try {
            Log.e("App", new String(error.networkResponse.data, "UTF-8"));
           } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
         }
       } 
       else {
         Log.e("App", "no network response");
       }
    }
});

requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

20% of the time I see:

```
E/App: [MainActivity] failed to post
E/App: no network response
```

but in my server logs I see a 200 message and the data created by the post is in my database.

Why would Volley throw an error on a successful post?

UPDATE

```
Log.e("App", "error message: " + error.getMessage());
```

prints: `E/App: error message: null`

Comment: have you know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

What is the error message returned by volley? Check it by `volleyError.getMessage()`.

Comment: its `null`. same for `getLocalizedMessage`

Comment: @Cbas have you monitored the response from the server by using tools like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/)? Check what volley gets from server.